# Breadth First Search for searching all paths between any two nodes in a cyclic Graph

Tags: data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search

I am trying to use BFS for getting all paths between two nodes in a cyclic Graph.
I found BFS doesnt't keep track its previous node, so need to add some other collection to achieve the same.

> Question is - Should we avoid using BFS to get all paths in a node and
>   use DFS or BFS can  as well give a potential solution.

If its there please provide me the logic for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you only want to find simple paths (with no cycles), otherwise there could be infinite paths. If this is not a requirement, either BFS or DFS would theoretically work (though DFS would just keep exploring one cycle and never find other shorter paths), but lifting this requirement doesn't really make sense.

With both BFS and DFS you should have a processed flag per node to prevent infinitely many paths in cyclic graphs.

Consider the following:

```
A with children B, C
B with children C, D
C with children B, D
```

With BFS, you'd miss A -> C -> B -> D because B would have been marked as processed before processing C.

With DFS, this wouldn't be a problem, because the processed flag should be reset when ascending back up the tree.

You could keep track of the entire path so far for each node, but this is not viable since it would require a lot of extra storage space and time.

You could get rid of the processed flag for BFS and stop processing when number of nodes in the path > number of nodes in the tree, and remove all non-simple paths from the output.